# Find which version of package is installed with pip

Tags: python, pip

Using pip, is it possible to figure out which version of a package is currently installed?

I know about `pip install XYZ --upgrade` but I am wondering if there is anything like `pip info XYZ`.  If not what would be the best way to tell what version I am currently using.

Answer (score 1637, accepted):

As of [pip 1.3](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/1.3/CHANGES.txt#L54), there is a `pip show` command.

```
$ pip show Jinja2
---
Name: Jinja2
Version: 2.7.3
Location: /path/to/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires: markupsafe
```

In older versions, `pip freeze` and `grep` should do the job nicely.

```
$ pip freeze | grep Jinja2
Jinja2==2.7.3
```

Comment: @techtonik: It's for [freezing current modules](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/1.1/requirements.html) to a requirements.txt.

Comment: The naming of 'freeze' is historical - it dates back to [at least 2008](https://github.com/pypa/pip/commit/97c152c463713bdaa0c1531a910eeae681035489#diff-65959455a7706e04f0827533ac39563bL133). At the time, many people were already familiar with "freezing" ruby gems, so pip borrowed the then-widely-used name.

Comment: this was not obvious nor documented, but you can type ```pip show pip``` to get pip's version info, rather than ```pip --version``` as I would've expected.

Comment: `pip freeze` has the advantage that it shows editable VCS checkout versions correctly, while `pip show` does not.

Comment: Wish they gave this an intuitive name like `pip info`. Is there any way to alias commands in pip?

Comment: I would suggest calling with -i flag as you sometimes do not know which ones are capital letters and which ones are not: `pip freeze | grep -i xyz`

Comment: As noted above the output of `pip show` doesn't include if a package was installed from a repository. `pip freeze` provides this implicitly by returning the URL of the repository and the commit. Another approach is to look in the [`direct_url.json`](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/direct-url/).

Answer (score 92):

I just sent a pull request in pip with the enhancement Hugo Tavares said:

(specloud as example)

```
$ pip show specloud

Package: specloud
Version: 0.4.4
Requires:
nose
figleaf
pinocchio
```

Comment: Looks like it is [merged](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-show) already.

Answer (score 64):

Pip 1.3 now also has a [list](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_list.html) command:

```
$ pip list
argparse (1.2.1)
pip (1.5.1)
setuptools (2.1)
wsgiref (0.1.2)
```

Comment: Say package name is X. To find the version - What is the difference between using pip list and doing import X and then X.__version__? Are both the package versions?

Comment: both are valid, but `pip list` is generic, and `__version__` is not. I have also seen `version()` and `get_version()` for the imported one.

Answer (score 46):

and with --outdated as an extra argument, you will get the Current and Latest versions of the packages you are using :

```
$ pip list --outdated
distribute (Current: 0.6.34 Latest: 0.7.3)
django-bootstrap3 (Current: 1.1.0 Latest: 4.3.0)
Django (Current: 1.5.4 Latest: 1.6.4)
Jinja2 (Current: 2.6 Latest: 2.8)
```

So combining with AdamKG 's answer :

```
$ pip list --outdated | grep Jinja2
Jinja2 (Current: 2.6 Latest: 2.8)
```

Check **pip-tools** too : https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools

Comment: An interesting option. I'd rather have it list all of them, and let me know if any of them are outdated, though.

Comment: You can also use `-o`

Answer (score 30):

The python function returning just the package version in a machine-readable format:

```
from importlib.metadata import version 
version('numpy')
```

Prior to python 3.8:

```
pip install importlib-metadata 
from importlib_metadata import version
version('numpy')
```

The bash equivalent (here also invoked from python) would be much more complex (but more robust - see caution below):

```
import subprocess
def get_installed_ver(pkg_name):
    bash_str="pip freeze | grep -w %s= | awk -F '==' {'print $2'} | tr -d '\n'" %(pkg_name)
    return(subprocess.check_output(bash_str, shell=True).decode())
```

Sample usage:

```
# pkg_name="xgboost"
# pkg_name="Flask"
# pkg_name="Flask-Caching"
pkg_name="scikit-learn"

print(get_installed_ver(pkg_name))
>>> 0.22
```

Note that in both cases `pkg_name` parameter should contain package name in the format as returned by `pip freeze` and not as used during `import`, e.g. `scikit-learn` not `sklearn` or `Flask-Caching`, not `flask_caching`.

Note that while invoking `pip freeze` in bash version may seem inefficient, only this method proves to be sufficiently robust to package naming peculiarities and inconsistencies (e.g. underscores vs dashes, small vs large caps, and abbreviations such as `sklearn` vs `scikit-learn`).

Caution: in complex environments both variants can return surprise version numbers, inconsistent with what you can actually get during `import`.

One such problem arises when there are other versions of the package hidden in a *user* `site-packages` subfolder. As an illustration of the perils of using `version()` here's a situation I encountered:

```
$ pip freeze | grep lightgbm
lightgbm==2.3.1

and

$ python -c "import lightgbm; print(lightgbm.__version__)"
2.3.1

vs.

$ python -c "from importlib_metadata import version; print(version(\"lightgbm\"))"
2.2.3

until you delete the subfolder with the old version (here 2.2.3) from the user folder (only one would normally be preserved by `pip` - the one installed as last with the `--user` switch):

$ ls /home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightgbm*
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightgbm-2.2.3.dist-info
/home/jovyan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lightgbm-2.3.1.dist-info
```

Another problem is having some conda-installed packages in the same environment. If they share dependencies with your pip-installed packages, and versions of these dependencies differ, you may get downgrades of your pip-installed dependencies.

To illustrate, the latest version of `numpy` available in PyPI on 04-01-2020 was 1.18.0, while at the same time Anaconda's `conda-forge` channel had only 1.17.3 version on `numpy` as their latest. So when you installed a `basemap` package with conda (as second), your previously pip-installed `numpy` would get downgraded by conda to 1.17.3, and version 1.18.0 would become unavailable to the `import` function. In this case `version()` would be right, and `pip freeze`/`conda list` wrong:

```
$ python -c "from importlib_metadata import version; print(version(\"numpy\"))"
1.17.3

$ python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)"
1.17.3

$ pip freeze | grep numpy
numpy==1.18.0

$ conda list | grep numpy
numpy                     1.18.0                   pypi_0    pypi
```

Comment: Why not use `importlib.metadata.version('NameOfProject')`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-versions

Comment: Great find @sinoroc! I think you should post it as an answer, and I will delete my rather overengineered one:) 
Sample PoC: 
`from importlib_metadata import version; version('Flask-Caching')`

Comment: I'll let you go for it

Comment: Your newest edits surprise me. Could you try `python -c "import pkg_resources; print(pkg_resources.get_distribution('lightgbm').version)"`?

Comment: That one gives you the correct answer - the latest version installed (2.3.1), when `version()` still returns the earliest (oldest) one (2.2.3). You can replicate this result by installing both versions with the `--user` switch, but preserving manually the `lightgbm-2.2.3.dist-info` folder, to have both of them together, as listed above (pip would *normally* remove it - until it doesn't).

Comment: You seem to have an unusual environment... Nonetheless, it might be worth reporting your findings on the [`importlib-metadata` issue tracker](https://gitlab.com/python-devs/importlib_metadata/issues). Might be something that is fixable (I would assume the version that gets imported by default should be the same found by `importlib.metadata.version`), or maybe the maintainers would explain why it works this way.

Comment: OK, I reported the issue, will move the discussion further. I preserved the containers that have this problem, and think I can replicate it, so hopefully will the devs. The multiple subfolders with lightgbm package most likely resulted from sharing the same `.local` folder by two different containers... possible not only under docker, but even under Openshift, which would not prevent the same user from installing multiple versions of the package to the same `.local` folder mapped to the local / network storage. It's enough to have 2 containers running in the same namespace...

Comment: The import_lib mechanism does not work if you package an app with py2app;  This is as of py2app 0.23

Answer (score 19):

You can use the grep command to find out.

```
pip show <package_name>|grep Version
```

Example:

```
pip show urllib3|grep Version
```

will show only the versions.

> Metadata-Version: 2.0
>   Version: 1.12

Comment: `grep` is for Unix, the Windows equivalent is `findstr` [(See @Quinn's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48959839/3936044)

Answer (score 18):

You can also install `yolk` and then run `yolk -l` which also gives some nice output.  Here is what I get for my little virtualenv:

```
(venv)CWD> /space/vhosts/pyramid.xcode.com/venv/build/unittest 
project@pyramid 43> yolk -l
Chameleon       - 2.8.2        - active 
Jinja2          - 2.6          - active 
Mako            - 0.7.0        - active 
MarkupSafe      - 0.15         - active 
PasteDeploy     - 1.5.0        - active 
Pygments        - 1.5          - active 
Python          - 2.7.3        - active development (/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload)
SQLAlchemy      - 0.7.6        - active 
WebOb           - 1.2b3        - active 
account         - 0.0          - active development (/space/vhosts/pyramid.xcode.com/project/account)
distribute      - 0.6.19       - active 
egenix-mx-base  - 3.2.3        - active 
ipython         - 0.12         - active 
logilab-astng   - 0.23.1       - active 
logilab-common  - 0.57.1       - active 
nose            - 1.1.2        - active 
pbkdf2          - 1.3          - active 
pip             - 1.0.2        - active 
pyScss          - 1.1.3        - active 
pycrypto        - 2.5          - active 
pylint          - 0.25.1       - active 
pyramid-debugtoolbar - 1.0.1        - active 
pyramid-tm      - 0.4          - active 
pyramid         - 1.3          - active 
repoze.lru      - 0.5          - active 
simplejson      - 2.5.0        - active 
transaction     - 1.2.0        - active 
translationstring - 1.1          - active 
venusian        - 1.0a3        - active 
waitress        - 0.8.1        - active 
wsgiref         - 0.1.2        - active development (/usr/lib/python2.7)
yolk            - 0.4.3        - active 
zope.deprecation - 3.5.1        - active 
zope.interface  - 3.8.0        - active 
zope.sqlalchemy - 0.7          - active
```

Answer (score 18):

pip show  works in python 3.7:

```
pip show selenium
Name: selenium
Version: 4.0.0a3
Summary: Python bindings for Selenium
Home-page: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/
Author: UNKNOWN
Author-email: UNKNOWN
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\python3.7\lib\site-packages\selenium-4.0.0a3-py3.7.egg
Requires: urllib3
Required-by:
```

Comment: It is not standard answer.

Answer (score 12):

[There's also a tool](https://pypi.org/project/pip-check/) called `pip-check` which gives you a quick overview of all installed packages and their update status:

[image]

Haven't used it myself; just stumbled upon it and this SO question in quick succession, and since it wasn't mentioned...

Comment: How to run this on windows

Comment: @vela I expect it would work exactly the same on Windows. Of course you would have to [install it](https://pypi.org/project/pip-check/) first, as you would on any system.

Answer (score 11):

`pip list` can also be told to format its output as `json`.
It could be a safer approach to parse the version.

```sh
pip list --no-index --format=json | \
  jq -r '.[] | select(.name=="Jinja2").version'
# 2.10.1
```

Comment: First time I've heard about the JSON output. Thanks, @Romain!

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is this:

```
import jinja2
print jinja2.__version__
```

Comment: This only works for packages that have defined `__version__` in their source code. Many packages do not.

Comment: Is it good practice to include this version while packaging or it is good practice to only have the version in the setup.py file version parameter?

Comment: This method is also not robust to package naming inconsistencies (there are at least 3 types) between the expected input of `import` and the output of `pip freeze`.

Answer (score 8):

On windows, you can issue command such as:

```
pip show setuptools | findstr "Version"
```

Output:

```
Version: 34.1.1
```

Answer (score 8):

To do this using Python code:

### Using [`importlib.metadata.version`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.metadata.html#distribution-versions)

#### Python ≥3.8

```py
import importlib.metadata
importlib.metadata.version('beautifulsoup4')
'4.9.1'
```

#### Python ≤3.7

(using [`importlib_metadata.version`](https://importlib-metadata.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#distribution-versions))

```py
!pip install importlib-metadata

import importlib_metadata
importlib_metadata.version('beautifulsoup4')
'4.9.1'
```

### Using [`pkg_resources.Distribution`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#distribution-attributes)

```py
import pkg_resources
pkg_resources.get_distribution('beautifulsoup4').version
'4.9.1'
pkg_resources.get_distribution('beautifulsoup4').parsed_version
<Version('4.9.1')>
```

---

Credited to comments by *sinoroc* and *mirekphd*.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows you can

1. open cmd and type python, press enter.
2. type the import  and press enter.
3. type ._version__ and press enter.

As you can see in screen shot here I am using this method for checking the version of serial module.

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

In question, it is not mentioned which OS user is using (Windows/Linux/Mac)

As there are couple of answers which will work flawlessly on Mac and Linux.

Below command can be used in case the user is trying to find the version of a python package on windows.

In PowerShell use below command :

`pip list | findstr <PackageName>`

Example:- `pip list | findstr requests`

Output : `requests    2.18.4`

Answer (score 0):

```
import pkg_resources
packages = [dist.project_name for dist in pkg_resources.working_set]
try:
   for count, item in enumerate(packages):
      print(item, pkg_resources.get_distribution(item).version)
except:
    pass here
```

The indentations might not be perfect. The reason I am using a Try- Except block is that few library names will throw errors because of parsing the library names to process the versions. even though packages variable will contain all the libraries install in your environment.