# PIP command to determine if the latest version is installed?

Tags: shell, versioning, python-imaging-library, pip

Is there a `pip` command that will determine whether the latest version of a package is installed?

I am writing a shell script that needs to determine if the latest version is installed. If not, then my script needs to manually install the package. (It's [PIL](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PIL) if anyone's curious and needs to be installed manually because the headers and libraries for `libjpeg` are in a non-standard location.)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10215100/193619) describes how to retrieve the version of the package currently installed, but I would also need the latest version available for download and some way to compare versions.

Comment: The best I know is that you can do `pip freeze` to get the current installed version of your packages. Then you could check that against the latest version of your packages (presumably from their homepages).

Comment: Maybe [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyPIXmlRpc?action=show&redirect=PyPiXmlRpc) will help.

Comment: "The XMLRPC interface for PyPI is considered legacy and should not be used. Use the Simple and JSON APIs" @NathanOsman

Answer (score 6):

A more useful command might be `pip list -o` which gives you a list of your out-dated libraries.

```
$ pip list -o
dj-database-url (0.3.0) - Latest: 0.4.0 [sdist]
...
```

You could do something like:

```
$ pip list -o | grep PIL
```

And see if it returns any output.

Answer (score 1):

'pip search' gives you that information. e.g.:

```
$ pip search SOAPpy
SOAPpy                    - SOAP Services for Python
  INSTALLED: 0.12.0
  LATEST:    0.12.5
```

versus:

```
$ pip search MarkupSafe
MarkupSafe                - Implements a XML/HTML/XHTML Markup safe string for Python
  INSTALLED: 0.19 (latest)
```

Comment: This func is being deprecated: ```pip search yapf
ERROR: XMLRPC request failed [code: -32500]
RuntimeError: PyPI's XMLRPC API is currently disabled due to unmanageable load and will be deprecated in the near future. See https://status.python.org/ for more information.```