# pip install from a file only if needed

Tags: python, installation, pip

I have a packages file (dependencies.conf) for pip including a bunch of packages that my app needs:

```
argparse==1.2.1
Cython==0.20.2
...
```

In my build process, I download all packages using:

```
pip install --download=build/modules -r conf/dependencies.conf
```

Then in the deployment process, I want to install these files only if the installed version is different than what I need and in the correct order (dependencies)

I'm currently using the following:

```
for f in modules/*; do pip install -I $f; done
```

But this is wrong since it doesn't validate the version (-I is there in order to downgrade packages if needed) and it doesn't handle the right order of dependencies.

Is there a simple method to do that? (I'm basically trying to update the packages in machines that don't have internet connection)

Answer (score 0):

Get the version using PIP, using the following command

eg. pip freeze | grep Jinja2
Jinja2==2.6

as explained in the following link [Find which version of package is installed with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214827/find-which-version-of-package-is-installed-with-pip)

then compare this with the version, and run pip install with the appropriate version if necessary

Comment: thanks, but the question was a bit more complicated than that. First, I download all packages (including dependencies), then I need to install the downloaded packages but I don't know the correct order (according to dependencies)