# How to check version of aiohttp

Tags: python

How do I check in Ubuntu 16.04, which version of aiohttp is installed?

This works

```
 python -V
 Python 2.7.12
```

but this doesn't

```
aiohttp -V
-bash: aiohttp: command not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A general way that works for pretty much any module, regardless of how it was installed is the following:

```
$ python -c "import aiohttp; print(aiohttp.__version__)"
2.3.3
```

What this does is run a Python interpreter, import the module, and print the module's `__version__` attribute. Pretty much all Python libraries define `__version__`, so this should be very general (especially since `__version__` is recommended by [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

This is analogous to:

```
$ python
>>> import aiohttp
>>> print(aiohttp.__version__)
2.3.3
>>> quit()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named aiohttp
Doest that mean aiohttp is not installed at all?

Comment: @GoodtheBest Yes that does. This requires that the module be installed. You must use the correct Python interpreter. If your default python installation is, for example, `python3`, substitute `python` with `python3`.

Comment: I've this version of Python 2.7.12 , how should I substitute in the command line suggested by you?

Comment: @GoodtheBest aiohttp is only supported (at least for recent-ish versions) for Python 3.x, Python 3.5.x specifically. 2.7 won't work. You need a new Python installation. See [here](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#dependencies).

Comment: Thanks Alexander Huszagh appreciate it.

Comment: aiohttp.__version__ works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a command line tool. That's why it says `command not found`. It is a `pip` package. So, you can do this:

```
pip freeze | grep aiohttp
```

to find the version.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed it with `pip` (>= 1.3), use

```
$ pip show aiohttp
```

For older versions,

```
$ pip freeze | grep aiohttp
```

`pip freeze` has the advantage that it shows editable VCS checkout versions correctly, while `pip show` does not.

... or

```
$ pip list | grep aiohttp
$ pip list --outdated | grep aiohttp
```

(`--outdated` to see Current and Latest versions of the packages).

**Credits**: [Find which version of package is installed with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214827/find-which-version-of-package-is-installed-with-pip)

**Note**: the property `__version__` comes in handy, but [it is not always available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20180597/2707864). This is an issue that evolved with time. YMMV.

Comment: I know that `__version__` isn't always available, but it's been highly recommended to package developers since 2001, and has been in long-term use since then. `pip` was released in 2011, and rightfully became the de-facto standard, but it will only work with packages installed by `pip`. This might not be true for packages built from source with `python setup.py install`, even though you can install those packages with pip just as well. IMO, I find `__version__` at least as reliable as `pip list | grep`, especially since it won't change user-to-user.