# Getting error when trying to install apache-airflow on Mac. How can I fix this?

Tags: pip, airflow

Error output below:

```
ronakvora:dtc ronakvora$ pip install apache-airflow
  Installing build dependencies ... done
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/pendulum.egg-info
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info/pendulum.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/pendulum.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/pendulum.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/pendulum.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/pendulum.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/6x/xsb52c7936l38mmb9f7s268m0000gn/T/pip-install-WFGcOd/pendulum/setup.py", line 50, in <module>
        setup(**setup_kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/6x/xsb52c7936l38mmb9f7s268m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-HZt1xp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 296, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "/private/var/folders/6x/xsb52c7936l38mmb9f7s268m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-HZt1xp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 303, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/private/var/folders/6x/xsb52c7936l38mmb9f7s268m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-HZt1xp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 534, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/private/var/folders/6x/xsb52c7936l38mmb9f7s268m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-HZt1xp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 570, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "/private/var/folders/6x/xsb52c7936l38mmb9f7s268m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-HZt1xp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py", line 36, in add_defaults
        self._add_defaults_ext()
      File "/private/var/folders/6x/xsb52c7936l38mmb9f7s268m0000gn/T/pip-build-env-HZt1xp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/py36compat.py", line 119, in _add_defaults_ext
        build_ext = self.get_finalized_command('build_ext')
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 312, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 159, in finalize_options
        self.include_dirs.append(py_include)
    AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'append'

----------------------------------------
```

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/6x/xsb52c7936l38mmb9f7s268m0000gn/T/pip-install-WFGcOd/pendulum/
>   You are using pip version 18.1, however version 19.0.1 is available.
>   You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't exactly solve the issue above, but just decided to switch to python3 and used pip3 install apache-airflow.

Comment: Oh yes, forgot to mention that I was on `Python 3.6.6`

Answer (score 1):

I had recently encountered a similar error on [`Airflow 1.10.2`](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/) and in my case it was related to incorrect version of `pendulum`

- Run `pip show pendulum`

  > Name: pendulum
  >
  > Version: 1.4.4
  >
  > Summary: Python datetimes made easy.
  >
  > ...
- If your version of `pendulum` is different from `v1.4.4` just do a *force-reinstall* (`Airflow 1.10.2` [requires `pendulum===1.4.4`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/setup.py#L325))

  `pip install --force-reinstall pendulum===1.4.4`

---

References

- [Find which version of package is installed with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10214827/3679900)
- [Installing specific package versions with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33812968/3679900)