# pylint no such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, pylint

I think I did not install pylint from the sources correctly. Which is a good occasion to learn how packages work in python.

I installed `pylint` from the sources, and I could see it in my pip list.

I wanted to uninstall it and install from pypi.

However, my 2 pips are empty, but when I use `pylint --version`

I got an error

> `bash: /usr/local/bin/pylint: no such file or directory`

Is there a way to remove this bash command? Pylint is probably installed, but I do not know where, or how to remove it ?

Edit: as suggested in comments, I tried this link [Find which version of package is installed with pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214827/find-which-version-of-package-is-installed-with-pip/21305641). Which gives me en empty answer aswell.

## What i tried so far

`which pylint`

`pip list | grep pylint`

`pip2 list | grep pylint`

All those commands give me empty answer, but I still have the same error when using pylint

Comment: There is an answer for this already..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214827/find-which-version-of-package-is-installed-with-pip/21305641

Comment: @DineshSakthivel Thank you, I did not know this, but it still returns an empty response, however the command `pylint` clearly shows there is a pylint installed somewhere, probably not with pip

Comment: If you want to know where it's installed, you enter `which pylint`.

Comment: @Dominique, oh, you are right, this gives me also an empty answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `whereis pylint`, I saw that pylint was pointing to an anaconda file. I just uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda to make it work.